# How does nonce verification work?

Tags: nonce, verification

I can see that wp_nonce_field generates a value in the hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" id="message-send" name="message-send" value="cabfd9e42d" />
```

But wp_verify_nonce isn't using that value as far as I can tell, but I may be wrong.

It looks like it's using a session token for verification.

```
$expected = substr( wp_hash( $i . '|' . $action . '|' . $uid . '|' . $token, 'nonce'), -12, 10 );
 if ( hash_equals( $expected, $nonce ) ) 
  { return 1;  }
```

Then what's the point of having a value attribute in the hidden field?

Comment: You've got the `$nonce` value there as well - the check returns false if `$nonce` value is missing.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but it only checks if it's not empty so it could be anything

Comment: we also got the `$nonce` value in this comparison: `hash_equals( $expected, $nonce )`

Comment: That's true. I was focusing on the value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### TL;DR

In short, `wp_verify_nonce()` **uses** that value because it *expects* that value as its first argument.

## `wp_verify_nonce()` arguments

[`wp_verify_nonce()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_verify_nonce/) receives 2 arguments:

1. `$nonce`
2. `$action`

The value in the hidden field (`'cabfd9e42d'` in your example) represent the `$nonce`.

### 1st argument is the nonce, and comes from the request

In fact, `wp_verify_nonce()` have to be used like so:

```
// here I assume that the form is submitted using 'post' as method

$verify = wp_verify_nonce($_POST['message-send']);
```

So the first argument passed to `wp_verify_nonce()` is exactly the value that is present in the hidden field.

### 2nd argument: the `wp_create_nonce()` method

Regarding the second argument, it depends on how you build the nonce value.

E.g. if you did:

```
<?php $nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'custom-action' ); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="message-send" value="<?php echo $nonce ?>" />
```

Then you need to do:

```
$verify = wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['message-send'], 'custom-action' );
```

So, the second argument is what was used as argument to [`wp_create_nonce()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_nonce/).

### 2nd argument: the `wp_nonce_field()` method

If you created the nonce using [`wp_nonce_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_field/) like:

```
wp_nonce_field( 'another_action', 'message-send' );
```

Then you need to verify the nonce like so:

```
$verify = wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['message-send'], 'another_action' );
```

So, this time, the action is whatever passed as first argument to `wp_nonce_field()`.

## Recap

To pass `wp_verify_nonce()` validation you need to pass 2 arguments to the function, one is the value in the nonce hidden field, the other is the *action*, and depends on how the nonce value was built.

Comment: @birgire I do typo like a pro :)

Comment: At least there are some pro English editors on the site to help us non native English typers clean up our typos, lol ;-). Great explanation BTW, +1